# How does one escape the # sign in a Url pattern in UrlMappings.groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy, escaping, urlmappings.groovy

In order to maintain the current set of Urls in a project, I have to be able to use the **#** (pound sign) in the Url.  For some reason the pound sign does not appear to work normally in this project for UrlMappings.groovy.

Is there a special **escape-sequence** that must be used when placing # signs in **UrlMappings.groovy**?

Am I missing some reason why one cannot use pound signs at all?

In the following URL Mapping example, the browser goes to the correct page, but the pageName variable is null:

```
"/test/${urlName}#/overview"(controller:'test', action:'overview') {
    pageName = "overview"
}
```

Comment: could you give a specific example for the desired url mapping?

Comment: @HoàngLong: jenny's working on the same project as me, so she posted an example.

Comment: test again, it doesn't work. It seems that netbrain is right: the url with "#" sign can be accepted by grails app, but it doesn't mapped to the right controller/action.

Comment: actually there's a way to escape "#" character, but may not like you expect. Please look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought everything after # in the url would be treated on the client side of the browsers where it tries to find a  and scroll to that location.

If you dump the request containing the pound char, do you even see the data behind #?

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize this: [Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

Answer (score 0):

I used a Named URL mapping and it works fine, no need to escape the "#" sign:

```
name test: "/#abc" (controller: 'test', action:'homepage')
```

EDIT: **My above answer is wrong**. In fact, it falls to a special case when homepage is the default action of the view.

Netbrain is right, the path after "#" will never be sent to server. In stead, I found that it's possible using "%23" instead of "#". Please take a look at [here](http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html).

For example, instead of `/test#/abc` we should use `/test%23/abc` as URL mapping (both at client side & server side).

Comment: It works, but additional variables in the URL Mapping are not being set for me.

Comment: @jenny: it seems the only thing we can do is replacing all "#" by "%23".

Comment: What we found out from further investigation is that anything passed after the # symbol (called the fragment identifier) is not sent to the server, it's strictly client-side: [Fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), so it can't be captured on the server-side.

Comment: @jenny: yeah. So the answer for this question is impossible. I have read your other question: it seems you need some javascript tricks to get around. Sorry I can't help anything further