# AJAX and urls with hash tags

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am developing AJAX application and want to make urls with hash tags. When users open such page (someting like #date=27.02.1990&Name=Alex) application recovery their state. Is there any libs which can help me?

Comment: hash tag # won't work in the url.

Read my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800103/how-does-one-escape-the-sign-in-a-url-pattern-in-urlmappings-groovy/5803541#5803541

Comment: @netbrain The OP is talking about doing it client-side.

Comment: What if i create many hidden "a tags" with necessery hash tags?

Comment: @lonesomeday I see, just disregard my comment then..

Comment: @lonesomeday Yeah, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) will help you achieve this, *plus* it will use `pushState` in newer browsers, so it changes the actual URL (without page reload) instead of just changing the fragment identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the [Asual jQuery Address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) should be able to help. It allows you to perform an action when the hash in the url changes. You can use this to load the appropriate content for the data in the hash via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work for you:

```
// Declare hashobj in global context
// So it can be used anywhere
window.hashobj = {};
var parts = location.hash.substring(1).split('&');

// Strip leading `?`
if(parts[0].lastIndexOf('?', 0) === 0)
    parts[0] = parts[0].substring(1);

// Create global variables
for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
    parts[i] = parts[i].split('=');
    hashobj[parts[i][0]] = parts[i][1];
}
alert(hashobj.date);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/VX9mX/)

Using that you should be able to read the hash easily enough and make the necessary Ajax requests to load the content.